# Rails blueimp fileupload - cannot select files in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, jquery-fileupload-rails

In my Rails App (3.2.12) I'm using the [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) gem to enable users ti upload profile pictures. Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari, but in Internet Explorer (I tested it with version 10) I can't even select files to upload. When I click the 'Add Files'-Button, instead of showing a dialog to select files he instantly fires an empty request to the upload action, resulting in a json response showing an empty photo object. This is my current js to initialize the fileupload (I already added some code from issues with IE and the csrf-tokens):

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|tiff)$/i
  });

  // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
  $('#fileupload').fileupload(
      'option',
      'redirect',
      window.location.href.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '/photos?%s')
  );

  //add csrf token manually for ie iframe transport
  $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsend', function(event, data) {
    auth_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    data.url = data.url + '?authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent(auth_token); 
    $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.send.call(this, event, data);
  });
```

and my controller code for the response, in which I already (hopefully correct) set the content type to 'text/plain':

```
format.html {
    render json: [@photo.to_jq_upload].to_json,
    content_type: 'text/plain', #content_type: 'text/html',
    layout: false
}
format.json { 
    render json: {files: [@photo.to_jq_upload]},
    content_type: 'text/plain',
    status: :created, 
    location: @photo
}
```

Does anyone know, how to get this to work in IE and can help me please? Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use Paperclip gem as it is being the widely used for file uploads. There is no cross browser issues with this.

Comment: Apparently the problem also occurs in Firefox and the main issue seems to be, that instead of opening the select file dialog he submits the empty form when the add files button is clicked...

Comment: Thanks, for the hint! I actually already use the paperclip gem but only for server file handling and image processing. Is there any client side magic I haven't heard about yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me quite some time to figure it out but in the end it was actually pretty simple: When applying my own styles I replaced the span-tag around the Add-Files-Button with a button-tag. This had no effect in the webkit browsers, however led to an immediate form submit in Firefox and Internet Explorer. Changing it back finally solved the issue :)